# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ibm.security.krb5.KrbException

Tags: jenkins-plugins, websphere-7

I have installed the websphere-deployer-plugin into my jenkins installation. I have done all the confgurations mentioned in https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/IBM+WebSphere+Configuration (copied the jar files, installed the certificate etc).

However, when I test the conenction, I get the following error.

```
Connection failed: com.ibm.websphere.management.exception.ConnectorException: ADMC0016E: The system cannot create a SOAP connector to connect to host xx.xxx.xx.xx at port 8879. 
at com.ibm.websphere.management.AdminClientFactory.createAdminClient(AdminClientFactory.java:529) 
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.websphere.services.deployment.WebSphereDeploymentService.connect(WebSphereDeploymentService.java:234) 
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.websphere_deployer.WebSphereDeployerPlugin$DescriptorImpl.doTestConnection(WebSphereDeployerPlugin.java:325)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) 
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) 
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601) 
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$InstanceFunction.invoke(Function.java:298) 
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvoke(Function.java:161) 
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvokeAndServeResponse(Function.java:96) 
at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$1.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:120) 
at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:53) 
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:728) 
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:858) 
at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$6.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:248) 
at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:53) 
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:728) 
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:858) 
at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$6.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:248) 
at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:53) 
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:728) 
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:858) 
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:631) 
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.service(Stapler.java:225) 
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210) 
at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:96) 
at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:88) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210) 
at hudson.security.csrf.CrumbFilter.doFilter(CrumbFilter.java:48) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210) 
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:84) 
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:76) 
at hudson.security.HudsonFilter.doFilter(HudsonFilter.java:164) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210) 
at org.kohsuke.stapler.compression.CompressionFilter.doFilter(CompressionFilter.java:46) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210) 
at hudson.util.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:81) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:164) 
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:591) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164) 
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100) 
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:562) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118) 
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:394) 
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:284) 
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:322) 
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1699) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603) 
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) 
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException 
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) 
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57) 
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) 
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525) 
at com.ibm.websphere.management.AdminClientFactory.createAdminClient(AdminClientFactory.java:358) 
... 58 more 
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/ibm/security/krb5/KrbException 
at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.soap.SOAPConnectorClient.reconnect(SOAPConnectorClient.java:309) 
at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.soap.SOAPConnectorClient.<init>(SOAPConnectorClient.java:197) 
... 63 more 
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ibm.security.krb5.KrbException 
at jenkins.util.AntClassLoader.findClassInComponents(AntClassLoader.java:1375) 
at jenkins.util.AntClassLoader.findClass(AntClassLoader.java:1325) 
at jenkins.util.AntClassLoader.loadClass(AntClassLoader.java:1078) 
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356) 
... 65 more
```

I tried changing the JDK to IBM JDK, but still the error persists.

Could anyone please help me.

Comment: Do you have SPNEGO enabled on your server? That class is in C:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\java\jre\lib\ibmjgssprovider.jar, so you might have wrong JDK configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must install the fix pack of your websphere version and copy the new jars to the plugin folder.